Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in dist folder
I was doing a short project on real time-chat, everything is working fine in development mode, but when I build the distfolder for deployment,It doesn't work
In my code there is no CommonJS code, as I am only working on only ECMAScript modules. But after building the project I am getting
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
And I have found that require does exist on my dist folder
require("websocket").w3cwebsocket;var Nw=require("websocket").w3cwebsocket

this is the part which is making error.
So,I tried to get rid of these require as it is showing as a error, But changing after vite.config.js file
  build: {
    target: 'modules',
  },

So, I don't get require, still it's not working. Can anyone help me with this?
